# 意図した通り scss が haml に反映されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, scss

views/tweets/index.html.haml に反映させたい _tweets.scss を、assets/modules/_tweets.scss として置いています。

application.scssは、

```
@import "reset";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "modules/tweets";
@import "modules/index";
```

としていますが、modules/index の scss が haml に反映されてしまっています。

どのようにすれば、上記のように反映させることができるでしょうか？
拙い文章で申し訳ありませんが、どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

後からインポートした `modules/_index.scss` のスタイルが `modules/_tweets.scss` で設定されたスタイルを上書きしてしまっているので、以下のようにインポートの順序を入れ替えばよいと思います。

```
@import "reset";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "modules/index";
@import "modules/tweets";
```

---

以下のようなSCSSを考えます。

```
// style.scss
@import "tweets";
@import "index";

// _tweets.scss
.hoge {
  color: red;
}

// _index.scss
.hoge {
    color: blue;
}
```

`style.scss` をCSSに変換すると、以下のようになります（https://sass.js.org/ で実験してみました）。

```css
.hoge {
  color: red;
}

.hoge {
  color: blue;
}
```

CSSは原則後に書かれたプロパティを優先して適用するので、この場合 `color: blue;` が適用され、`color: red;` は無視されることになります。